# How to use jquery to submit a post to a different uri than the current page in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Using the submit function from jquery, how can I get it to post to a uri other than the current page?

For example, I would like the post to go to /comments as opposed to /user/blog.  I've looked at the jQuery [API page for submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) but I don't see something about posting to a different page.  Here's the start of the javascript:

```
jQuery(function() {
  return $('.comment_input').find('form').submit(function(e) {
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to set the action on the form so it doesn't post to the same page:

```
<form action="/comments">
```

You can also set it with jQuery on page load:

```
jQuery(form).attr( 'action', '/comments' );
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set form action to be url where you want to post

2.Then use jQuery to activate submit button

```
$('#your-submit-id').click();
```

But if you want to post it using AJAX, to different domain, then I'm really sorry but that is not possible.

Only one way can be possible is to create invisible iFrame, copy your form into iFrame and then submit it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set the `action` attribute on the form element?